# Write words in a .txt document without repeat

Tags: python, selenium

So I'm trying to pick words in a website and write them in a `.txt` document in python. I need to do this every time a new word appears, but that is not the problem. The problem is every time I run the code the `.txt` repeats the same words.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=D:/Users/daichi/Desktop/Bot/chrome')
url = 'https://web.whatsapp.com/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/daichi/Desktop/Bot/chromedriver/chromedriver', options = options)
words = open("words.txt","r+") 

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
user = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@title="A"]')
user.click()
time.sleep(2)
messages = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[text()[contains(.,"!web")]]')
for message in messages:
   if message.text in words.read():
        print("this word is alrealy on the .txt!")
   elif message.text not in words.read():
        words.write(message.text + "\n")
```

Sorry for my bad English and hi from Brazil.

Comment: You may be interested in [pt.so] in the future.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.
Your posted code fails on undefined symbols and files.  Your generic problem description is unclear: why should the program *not* do the same thing when you run it again?

Comment: What is `palavras`? A file? How is that formatted?

Answer (score 0):

you are always reading the same file.

```
twetts = ['new 1','new 2','new 2']

for twett in twetts:
    if twett in open('palavras.txt','r').read():
        print("the word is alrealy in the txt")
    else:
        wf = open('palavras.txt','a')
        wf.write(f"{twett}\n")
        wf.close()
```